# c# winforms linq запрос по List

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

Есть лист

```
List.Add( new {tovar_code:1, tovar_kol:10, tovar_obyem:20}  )
List.Add( new {tovar_code:2, tovar_kol:20, tovar_obyem:30}  )
List.Add( new {tovar_code:3, tovar_kol:30, tovar_obyem:60}  )
List.Add( new {tovar_code:4, tovar_kol:40, tovar_obyem:80}  )
List.Add( new {tovar_code:5, tovar_kol:50, tovar_obyem:90}  )
```

Как получить всего количество товаров и их объемы одним `linq` запросом ( Всего кол 150, всего объем 280)?

Answer (score 2):

Вы хотите общее количество и общий объём? Тогда проще всего просто

```
var total_quantity = List.Sum(x => x.tovar_kol);
var total_volume = List.Sum(x => x.tovar_obyem);
```

Если хочется и правда в один запрос, попробуйте так:

```
var result =
    List.Aggregate(
        new { total_quantity = 0, total_volume = 0 },
        (sum, curr) => new { total_quantity = sum.total_quantity + curr.tovar_kol,
                             total_volume = sum.total_volume + curr.tovar_obyem });
```

(но не думаю, что это выглядит лучше, плюс это аллоцирует по одному временному объекту на итерацию).

Ну и в конце-концов не забывайте про старый добрый цикл `foreach`:

```
int total_quantity_2 = 0;
double total_volume_2 = 0;
foreach (var item in List)
{
    total_quantity_2 += item.tovar_kol;
    total_volume_2 += item.tovar_obyem;
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/opDSgz

Answer (score 1):

Сгруппируем по общему для всех записей, не зависящему от элементов списка, ключу. Например, по цифре 1. И посчитаем сумму:

```
            var res=List.GroupBy(x=>1)
                .Select(x=>new 
                            {
                                sum_kol=x.Sum(s=>s.tovar_kol), 
                                sum_obyem=x.Sum(s=>s.tovar_obyem)
                            })
                .DefaultIfEmpty(new {sum_kol=0, sum_obyem=0})
                .First();
```